# What does this definition of a function mean?

Tags: definition

I've never seen before the following function definition.

[Image taken from Ch. 2 of the book "Principles of Eventual Consistency"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm5Kl.png)

What does it try to convey in this specific form and how does it differ from the commonly used notation?

*(The book is freely accesible from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/final-printversion-10-5-14.pdf)*

Comment: Be careful. The author is defining a partial function, not a function. Partial functions don't have to be defined on every point in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve not seen the notation before, but it appears that:

- $(A\to B)$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$;
- $(A\rightharpoonup B)$ is the set of partial functions from $A$ to $B$, i.e., the set of all functions whose domains are subsets of $A$ and whose ranges are subsets of $B$; and
- $(A\times B)$ is the set of all relations from $A$ to $B$, so that it is simply $\wp(A\times B)$.

Thus, $(A\to B)\subseteq(A\rightharpoonup B)\subseteq(A\times B)$: every function from $A$ to $B$ is a partial function, and every partial function is a relation.

Finally, if $f:A\rightharpoonup B$ is a partial function (and I’m including the possibility that $f$ is a total function, i.e., with domain all of $A$), $a\in A$, and $b\in B$, we can define a new function $f[a\mapsto b]$ whose domain is $\{a\}\cup\operatorname{dom}(f)$:

$$f[a\mapsto b](x)=\begin{cases}
b,&\text{if }a=b\\
f(x),&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

This function sends $a$ to $b$ but otherwise acts exactly as $f$ does.